# Attaching an onClickListener to all buttons inside a container

Tags: android, onclicklistener

A question of laziness =)

I've got an XML layout filled with buttons (no other View objects except for Buttons present). How to attach one listener to all the buttons without having to paste the line "android:onClick" to each of them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ViewGroup yourLayout = ...;
View.OnClickListener ocl = ...;
for(int i=0; i<yourLayout.getChildCount(); i++)
    if(yourLayout.getChildAt(i) instanceof Button)
        yourLayout.getChildAt(i).setOnClickListener(ocl);
```

`ViewGroup` might me `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout` or other - mainly: container with your `Button`s

Answer (score 0):

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_your);
        ....
        btnA.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnB.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnC.setOnClickListener(this);
     }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     //do your stuff here
    }

}
```